# How to copy columns from several csv files into a single csv file with python?

Tags: python, csv

I have several one column csv files in a directory named path and I want to merge all these column in a single files and store that file as `out.csv` in a directory named `repsim`. 
here is my code:

Suppose that I have already the list `files` and `fin=files[0]`

```
def ajouter (fin, files, out, path, repsim, delim=';'):
    fic=os.path.join(path,fin)
    with open(fic, 'rb') as fr:
        print fic + " est overt"
        tout=[]
        for i in range(1, len(files)):
            fil=files[i]
            print fil + " en cours -------------"
            f=os.path.join(path,fil)
            with open(f, 'rb') as fi:
                fr_reader = csv.reader(fr, delimiter=delim)
                fi_reader = csv.reader(fi, delimiter=delim) 

                for row1, row2 in zip(fr_reader, fi_reader):
                    row2.append(row1[-1])
                    tout.append(row2)

        fout=os.path.join(repsim,out)
        with open(fout, 'ab') as output: 
            writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=delim)
            writer.writerows(tout)
```

This code only give me a two columns file consisting of the column of `files[0]` and the column of the last file in files.

Comment: Do you want to stack columns? Do you want to keep columns side by side? What should happen if two files contain a column with the same name? Can you provide two example input CSV files and the corresponding expected output file?

Comment: And by the way, I would use `pandas` for this. It can read CSV files, then stack and/or merge data sets and write a new CSV file in a few lines only.

Comment: i want columns side by side, each files has a unique column name.

Comment: for example, file1=>column bw64 having ten rows, file2=> column hop64 having also 10 rows and file3=> column recall64 having ten row too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While this might be an interesting exercise for you, there is need to re-invent the wheel. This is straight-forward using e.g. [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
import pandas as pd
dataframes = [pd.read_csv(p) for p in ("data1.csv", "data2.csv")]
merged_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)
merged_dataframe.to_csv("merged.csv", index=False)
```

Input:

```
$ cat data1.csv 
data1
a
b
c
d
$ cat data2.csv 
data2
p
q
r
s
```

Output:

```
$ cat merged.csv 
data1,data2
a,p
b,q
c,r
d,s
```

Comment: pandas module prints errors: it says ValueError: Shape of passed values is (1,42) indices imply (1,24). i have no idea about this error and it the first time i use pandas.

Comment: `pandas` is still the way to go, that error most likely is easily fixed. As you can see, the minimal example works. Probably your data differs from the data in my minimal example in some significant way. Identify that difference and tell us. Also, you should show code and a traceback.

Comment: this is how i use your code :`def merge (files, out, path, repsim):
    dataframes = [pd.read_csv(os.path.join(path,p)) for p in files]
    merged_dataframe = pd.concat(dataframes, axis=1)
    merged_dataframe.to_csv(os.path.join(repsim,out), index=False)`

Comment: my files like this: file1=> one column with an unique name Cname (e.g bw64) and 10 rows having int values.

Comment: may error is caused by my files separator! in my csv files, the separator i use is `';'` and not the default `','`.

Comment: thank you it works well. the problem was the separator.

Answer (score 0):

`itertools.izip` is perfect for this sort of thing since it does not require you to read the files into memory.  It works just like `zip` except that it returns an iterator instead of a list of tuples.  Something like the following should work.

```
import csv
import os
from itertools import izip, chain

def ajouter(files, out, path, repsim, delim=';'):

    try:
        open_files = [open(os.path.join(path, file_)) for file_ in files]
        readers = (csv.reader(f, delimiter=delim) for f in open_files)
        merged_cols = (tuple(chain.from_iterable(row)) for row in izip(*readers))


        with open(os.path.join(repsim, out), 'wb') as output:
            writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter=delim)
            writer.writerows(merged_cols)
    finally:
        for open_file in open_files:
            open_file.close()
```

Comment: it works but in the output file, column values are formated like this ['0.65']. Can you help me to modify this?